# Australian resident working in the UK - Can I apply for a French Visa from the UK?

Tags: visas, france

I am an Australian Resident, I obtained a UK youth mobility scheme Visa valid for another year. I would like to work a winter ski season in France. Can I apply for a French Visa from the UK or would I need to return to Australia?

Comment: As an Aussie you don't need a visa to visit France. I have no idea if you current residency in the UK gives you the right to work in France - that could be an "expat question" - we don't aim to be expert in the expat area. Aussies can get a working holiday visa for France though.

Comment: If this question still matters to you, the [Expatriates SE site has now launched](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com), and you may wish to re-ask it there if you'd like to get further information or answers

Answer (score 1):

In principle, you should apply in your country of residence. Coming to France to work can also be difficult. As far as I know, your future employer needs to make a special request to the authorities *before* applying for the visa. Just coming to France hoping to find work is not generally legally possible.

You said you are an Australian resident but wouldn't a UK youth mobility scheme visa for a year be enough to make you a UK resident for this purpose? That would enable you to apply at France's consulates in the UK. I would just stress the fact that my UK visa allows me to come back there, avoid presenting myself as an Australian resident and just see if the consulate is OK with it.

If you are an Australian citizen, you might also want to consider a “work holiday visa”. This would allow you to come to France and look for work but there are some conditions and I am not sure if you can apply for it from outside your country of origin.